# How to do a left join on a select statement in JPQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to write the following **native** query in jpql. However I fail to find any way.

Native query is something like this:

```
select * from table1 t1 left join (select * from table2 t2 where ....) temp 
on t1.id = temp.foreignId where ....;
```

I would like to understand how we can write this in jqpl.

I am new to jpql. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your query doesn't contain with, so the error doesn't match your query. Please update the post with your goal. Preferably with all of the necessary statements and expected output so that someone answering the question can assist without guessing or assuming your intentions.

Comment: Am not familiar with JPQL, but found this over. Check this out https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types